# Reference custom column created in SELECT

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to reference column short hand names created above to greatly simplify a `DATE_DIFF` line for readability, but am unsure if this is allowed.

---

**Is something like below code possible?** Notice that the inputs to the `DATE_DIFF` were initiated in the 2 preceding lines.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Stuff ,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date1), '%Y-%d-%m') as Date_Start ,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date2), '%Y-%d-%m') as Date_End  ,
    DATE_DIFF( 'day' , Date_Start , Date_End) + 1 as Date_Delta ,    `<-- HERE
    More_Stuff 
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
    ON Stuff = More_Stuff
LEFT JOIN T3
    ON More_Stuff = Other_Stuff
```

---

I am hoping to avoid nesting the full query for `Date_Start` & `Date_End` inside the `DATE_DIFF` or using yet another `Join`. If this is something that cannot be done, then the question can be converted to **What is best practice for something like this and why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would either be looking at:

```
SELECT
    Stuff
    , Date_Start
    , Date_End
    , DATE_DIFF( 'day' , Date_Start , Date_End) + 1 as Date_Delta
    , More_Stuff
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            Stuff ,
            DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date1), '%Y-%d-%m') as Date_Start ,
            DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date2), '%Y-%d-%m') as Date_End  ,
            DATE_DIFF( 'day' , Date_Start , Date_End) + 1 as Date_Delta ,
            More_Stuff 
        FROM T1
        LEFT JOIN T2
            ON Stuff = More_Stuff
        LEFT JOIN T3
            ON More_Stuff = Other_Stuff
    ) as Q
```

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Stuff ,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date1), '%Y-%d-%m') as Date_Start ,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date2), '%Y-%d-%m') as Date_End  ,
    DATE_DIFF( 'day' , DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date1), '%Y-%d-%m') , DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(date2), '%Y-%d-%m')) + 1 as Date_Delta ,
    More_Stuff 
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
    ON Stuff = More_Stuff
LEFT JOIN T3
    ON More_Stuff = Other_Stuff
```

To use a field in the `SELECT` part, it must exist in the `FROM` part.

Comment: well that is disappointing. That you for confirming what I feared, though!